# Put data from controller to jsp page using shortest code ever?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, hibernate, jsp

need code improvement thanks

Current way of loading/displaying data to page is:

```
$.getJSON('${cp}/'+url+'/'+myCode, function(response){
            $.each(response, function(index, item){                         
                switch(index) {
                    case "code":
                        $("#code").val(item);
                        break;
                    case "name":
                        $("#name").val(item);
                        break;
                    case "street1":
                        $("#street1").val(item);
                        break;
                    case "street2":
                        $("#street2").val(item);
                        break;
                    case "postalCode":
                        $("#postalCode").val(item);
                        break;
            }
        });//end of each
    });//end of getJson
```

controller code is:

```
@RequestMapping(value="url/{myCode}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Supplier getSupplier(@PathVariable("myCode")
            Integer myCode, HttpSession session) {
        setTable();
        Supplier supp = srvSupplier.get(myCode);
        return supp;
    }
```

thanks must be on button click

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
$.each(response, function( key, item ){                         
    $("#" + key).val(item);
});
```